# This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur - custom Chronometer

Tags: android

First of all, even though this question might've been already answered before, I still don't know how to fix this issue, as I've never used `WeakReferences` and despite reading some answers/examples I still don't know how to.

The app I'm developing will have a Chronometer that displays minutes, seconds and **milliseconds**, which is something the original Android Chronometer can't do. So I looked around for some alternatives and found a [GitHub library](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer/blob/master/src/gr/antoniom/chronometer/Chronometer.java) that is essentially a modified Chronometer.
Upon importing the library, I noticed a Lint warning saying

> This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous android.os.Handler)

at line 147:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        if (mRunning) {
            updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            dispatchChronometerTick();
            sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(this , TICK_WHAT),
                    100);
        }
    }
};
```

It looks like the recommended fix is making the Handler class `static` and using `WeakReferences` for accessing the UI. So, after replacing the `private Handler mHandler = new Handler()` with `private static class mHandler extends Handler`, the warning is gone... but now some errors showed up.
The boolean `mRunning` and the methods `updateText(long)` and `dispatchChronometerTick()` can't be referenced from a static context.

After making them `static`, now more of the same errors but on different variables show up. After making them `static` too, I'm obligated to undo what I just did because [`setText(text);`](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer/blob/caf3cad5d5ee229a627157fb85cdcf725f9716c4/src/gr/antoniom/chronometer/Chronometer.java#L129) and [`com.example.myapp.Chronometer.this`](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer/blob/caf3cad5d5ee229a627157fb85cdcf725f9716c4/src/gr/antoniom/chronometer/Chronometer.java#L152) can't be referenced from a static context, which would show the previous errors again; and make [`sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message, long)`](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer/blob/caf3cad5d5ee229a627157fb85cdcf725f9716c4/src/gr/antoniom/chronometer/Chronometer.java#L138)   and [`removeMessages(int)`](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer/blob/caf3cad5d5ee229a627157fb85cdcf725f9716c4/src/gr/antoniom/chronometer/Chronometer.java#L141) `static`, which I believe can't be done from the code. (Click on the links to see what lines I'm talking about).

So by fixing something, an error appears elsewhere and I'll have to undo what I did.

If someone could help me fix this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we should talk about why Android Studio warning this message. When you create `Handler()` and declare callback `handleMessage`. It is the anonymous class and it can refer to the instance of the outer class. This can be leak when outer class dead but callback still gets called. For example, when you declare in Activity callback `handleMessage` can be call when your Activity `destroy`.

There are two ways to fix it (I assume you declare it in Activity)

1. Ignore the warning and inside onDestroy call `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`
2. Make class MyHanler like that

```
    public class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private WeakReference<YourActivity> weakReference;
        public MyHandler(YourActivity activity) {
            weakReference = new WeakReference<YourActivity>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (weakReference != null && weakReference.get() != null) {
                YourActivity activity = weakReference.get();
                if (activity.mRunning) {
                    activity.updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    activity.dispatchChronometerTick();
                    sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(this, TICK_WHAT),
                            100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clear explanation, thank you! The warning is now gone, I just needed to change any `mHandler` references to `MyHandler()`.
But I've decided to use another library, as this one for some reason only counts milliseconds.
Anyways, now I have an idea of how to use `weakReferences` because of your example. Thanks again!